# Image not uploaded when publishing a story using Facebook SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm following the official FB tutorial for publishing stories using the share dialog:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/open-graph#sharedialog

I already configured my facebook app and I set up the correct capabilities on the action (just like is described on the tutorial). I double and triple checked every step.

The story is published, but the image does not appear on the post. When the share dialog appears, the thumbnail of the image is shown, then I tap on "Post" and I can see the progress of the bar that indicates the uploading, but at the end I get a post without an image.

I downloaded the tutorial app sources, compiled it and I got the same result (https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-howtos/tree/master/FBOGSampleSD).

Comment: I'm using the share dialog, not the feed dialog, that AFAIK does not support image uploading.

Comment: @BhaveshNai: you don't need to let users know that you've answered a question, as the system automatically notifies the OP if they have received answers. Comments like these are unnecessary and may be removed by moderators. For more information about comments, take a look at the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is probably related to this bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/456750217796696/

It's been fixed but I don't think the update has been released yet.

One thing you could do in the meantime is upload the image to Facebook's staging servers from your app before sending the action to the share dialog, but this would force you to get publish permissions from the user through your app, which admittedly isn't great but would at least get your images up there.

```
[FBRequestConnection startForUploadStagingResourceWithImage:image completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection* connection, id result, NSError* error) {
    if(!error)
    {
        [newImageInfo setObject: [result objectForKey:@"uri"] forKey: @"url"];
        [fbObject setObject: @[newImageInfo] forKey: @"image"];

        // Setup action with fbObject property, then send action to native Share Dialog
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"[ERROR] Could Not Stage Image: %@", error.description);
    }
}];
```